# Can you use default parameters inside functions, like you can in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I am trying to include a default parameter in a function (rather than a stored procedure). I can't get it to work, everywhere I try to call it without the default parameter passed it gives me the error '..insufficient parameters..'.

Is it possible to use default parameters for any of the following, and if so, it seems it must be handled differently, so how do you do it:

- Table-valued Functions
- Scalar-valued Functions
- Aggregate Functions
- System Functions

I have tried googling this, and searching through SO, but everything I could find only dealt with stored parameters, which just doesn't work in this situation.

---

Edit: This is how I was attempting to create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction (@firstparam bit, @secondparam bit = 1) RETURNS @retparam table (columnname bit)
```

I would then try and call it with something along the lines of

```
SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.uid IN (select columnname from dbo.MyFunction(1))
```

This results in the error '..Insufficient parameters..'

Comment: . . Put in the full function definition.  The error may be in the body of the function and not in your call to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default values for parameters but not like you can with procedures. You have to specify all parameters and use the keyword `default` for the parameter where you want to use the default value.

```
create function dbo.GetIt(@P1 int = -1) returns int
as
begin
  return @P1;
end

go

select dbo.GetIt(default);
```

Result:

```
-1
```

From: [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

> When a parameter of the function has a default value, the keyword
>   DEFAULT must be specified when the function is called to retrieve the
>   default value. This behavior is different from using parameters with
>   default values in stored procedures in which omitting the parameter
>   also implies the default value. However, the DEFAULT keyword is not
>   required when invoking a scalar function by using the EXECUTE
>   statement.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

I guess only the truly desperate look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).  It is pretty clear that default parameters are supported.  Here is the relevant part of the syntax:

> CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name( [ { @parameter_name [
>
> AS ][ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type
>
> ```
> [ = **default** ] [ READONLY ] } 
>
> [ ,...n ]   ] )
> ```

Followed a bit further down with:

> [ = default ]
>
> Is a default value for the parameter. If a default value is defined,
>   the function can be executed without specifying a value for that
>   parameter.

You provide no hint as to what you are doing, but functions do not use the `default` keyword.  They just use `=`.

Comment: I've added an example as to how I was setting it up and calling it